# Brute Force Post via Hydra

Tags: hydra

I am trying to brute force an HTTP login form via Hydra.

The problem I am having is in regards to the response code returned by the page. I am receiving false positives on every password.

Even failed logins return HTTP 200 responses, which I believe is leading to false positives.

How can I alter hydra to look for something like content-length header or a unique string returned to avoid the false positives?

Comment: in the hydra command you use, you specify what hydra is to look for to determine if the login was successful

Comment: @schroeder unfortunately i do not know what success looks like. I just know if it fails, what html is rendered

Comment: Then the problem is not the 200 response, but your understanding of the system.

Answer (score 2):

Getting a `200` response is fine. You need to tell `Hydra` what to look for in the response page.

For example, if I log into `SocialSite.com/login.php` and my creds are wrong, the login page will return with a message of `Bad username or password!`

You can do this by adding some of this text to the end of your hydra command

```
hydra 192.168.1.69 http-form-post "socialsite.com/login.php:user=^USER^&pass=^PASS^:Bad username" ...
```

notice at the end of the http-form-post arg there's `:Bad username"` That tells hydra to look for that text in the response.

[Here's a full example for you to reference](http://insidetrust.blogspot.com/2011/08/using-hydra-to-dictionary-attack-web.html)

Comment: I did this, as entering poor credentials renders a tag that says "Login Error". So, exactly as you did, added Login Error at the end....and I am still getting false positives :(

Comment: @Hysii I would look more at what you're doing then because this is the answer. Maybe there's a piece of the picture you're missing

Comment: Possibly locked accounts or rate limiting is changing the page output, you can always run hydra via a proxy like burp and verify.